# How to create a non consuming iterator from a Vector

Tags: rust

**Situation:**

I have a situation where I would like to call some method defined on the `Iterator` trait on a function parameter. The function that I would like to call it is taking a parameter of a type which is a `trait` called `VecLike`. The function is called `get_all_matching_rules`.

`get_all_matching_rules` can receive either a `Vec` or another similar *home made* type which also implements `Iterator`. Of course both of these implement `VecLike`. I was thinking of adding a function on `VecLike` to have it return an `Iterator` so that I could use it in `get_all_matching_rules`.

If my parameter is named: `matching_rules` I could then do `matching_rules.iter().filter(`.

**Question:**

How do I return a non consuming iterator from a `Vec`?

I'd like to be able to return a non consuming iterator on a `Vec<T>` of type `Iterator<T>`. I am not looking to iterate the items by calling `.iter()`.

If I have (where self is a Vec):

```
fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Iterator<T> {
    self.iter()
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `core::iter::Iterator<T>+'a`, found `core::slice::Items<'_,T>` (expected trait core::iter::Iterator, found struct core::slice::Items)
```

I would like to return the `Iterator<t>`. If there is a better way to go at this rather than returning an `Iterator`, I'm all ears.

Comment: I have edited my question as I wasn't clear before. Sorry it's totally my fault. If I can make further improvements, please let me know.

Comment: (on mobile, cant update answer) Iterator is a trait, you can't return it. You can return Box<Iterator<T>> or U where U:Iterator<T>.

Comment: (also, still unclear on what's wrong with returning Items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`.iter()` on `[T]`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), which `Vec<T>` automatically dereferences to, takes self by reference and produces a type implementing `Iterator<&T>`. Note that the return type is *not* `Iterator<&T>`; `Iterator` is a *trait* which is implemented by concrete types, and the concrete type `Items<T>` is the return type in that case, not `Iterator<&T>`. There is not currently any syntax for specifying a return type merely as a trait that is implemented by it, though the syntax `impl Iterator<&T>` has been suggested.

Now you wish something implementing `Iterator<T>` rather than `Iterator<&T>`. Under Rust’s memory model where each object is owned by exactly one thing, this is not possible *with the same objects*; there must be some constraint to allow you to get a new `T` from the `&T`. There are two readily provided solutions for this:

1. The [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html) trait, for types that can just be copied bitwise. Given a variable of a type implementing `Iterator<&T>` where `T` is `Copy`, this can be written `.map(|&x| x)` or `.map(|x| *x)` (the two are equivalent).
2. The [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait, for any types where the operation can be caused to make sense, regardless of `Copy` bounds. Given a variable of a type implementing `Iterator<&T>` where `T` is `Clone`, this can be written `.map(|x| x.clone())`.

Thus, given a vector `v`, `v.iter().map(|x| x.clone())`. Generically, something like this:

```
fn iter<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> Map<&T, T, Items<T>> {
    slice.iter().map(|x| x.clone())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking here.

`.iter()` creates an iterator (`Items`) which does not move the `Vec` (You'll get an Iterator over `&T`).

`Filter` (and most other iterator adapters) are lazy. Perhaps you should [`chain()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.chain) the two iterators before filtering them?

Otherwise, if you don't want the `Filter` to be consumed, clone it.