# Implement a pairwise iterator

Tags: iterator, rust

I have trouble writing code for a function that takes an iterator and returns an iterator that iterates in pairs `(Option<T>, T)` like so

```
a = [1,2,3]
assert pairwise(a) == `[(None, 1), (Some(1), 2), (Some(2), 3)]
```

```rust
fn pairwise<I, T>(&xs: &I) -> I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    [None].iter().chain(xs.iter().map(Some)).zip(xs.iter())
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let newdata: Vec<Option<i32>, i32> = pairwise(&data).collect();
    println!("{:?}", newdata);
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for type `I` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:28
  |
3 |     [None].iter().chain(xs.iter().map(Some)).zip(xs.iter())
  |                            ^^^^
  |
```

Not sure why `xs` isn't iterable. I've stated it in the `where` clause haven't I?

Comment: `.iter()` is for creating an iterator, but you've already got one. `xs` is already an `Iterator`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh, okay. What is the type for something that has `.iter()` method?

Comment: I don't believe there is one. There is however an `IntoIterator` which defines the `into_iter()` method. This is automatically implemented for all `Iterator`s, so if you have an API that takes an `IntoIterator` and you don't want to actually consume the argument, the caller can just call `.iter()` themselves and pass in the resulting iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> fn pairwise<I, T>(&xs: &I) -> I
> ```

This doesn't make sense. See [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423) and [What is the difference between `e1` and `&e2` when used as the for-loop variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45197826/155423).

> ```
> I: Iterator<Item = T>,
> ```

There's no reason to specify that the `Item` is a `T`.

> ```
> [None].iter()
> ```

It's better to use [`iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html).

> ```
> xs.iter()
> ```

There's no trait in the standard library that defines an `iter` method. Perhaps you meant [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html)?

> ```
> let data: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3]
> ```

There's no reason to specify the type here; `i32` is the default integral type.

> ```
> Vec<Option<i32>, i32>
> Vec<Option<i32>, i32>> // original version
> ```

This is not a valid type for `Vec`, and your original form doesn't even have balanced symbols.

---

After all that, you are faced with tough choices. Your example code passes in an iterator which has *references* to the slice but you've written your assertion such that you expect to get non-references back. You've also attempted to use an arbitrary iterator twice; there's no guarantee that such a thing is viable.

The most generic form I see is:

```rust
use std::iter;

fn pairwise<I>(right: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = (Option<I::Item>, I::Item)>
where
    I: IntoIterator + Clone,
{
    let left = iter::once(None).chain(right.clone().into_iter().map(Some));
    left.zip(right)
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let newdata: Vec<_> = pairwise(&data).collect();
    assert_eq!(newdata, [(None, &1), (Some(&1), &2), (Some(&2), &3)]);

    let newdata: Vec<_> = pairwise(data.iter().copied()).collect();
    assert_eq!(newdata, [(None, 1), (Some(1), 2), (Some(2), 3)]);
}
```

See also:

- [Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613725/155423)
- [How to iterate over and filter an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467085/155423)
- [How to create a non consuming iterator from a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26953280/155423)
- [Why can I iterate over a slice twice, but not a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34572784/155423)
- [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I don't understand only one thing. Why is `Box` needed here?

Comment: @user1685095 The linked question ["What is the correct way to return an Iterator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator) answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I know OP asked for "outer pairwise" (`[(None, 1), (Some(1), 2), (Some(2), 3)]`), but here is how I adapted it for "inner pairwise" (`[(1, 2), (2, 3)]`):</s>

```rs
fn inner_pairwise<I>(right: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = (I::Item, I::Item)>
where
    I: IntoIterator + Clone,
{
    let left = right.clone().into_iter().skip(1);
    left.zip(right)
}
```

For anyone here for "inner pairwise", you're looking for [`Itertools::tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows).

Comment: I believe that's [`Itertools::tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows)

Comment: It is, silly me.